# Yield item in a list

Tags: c#, yield

In my application there is a `List<MyItem>` with a getter only:

```
public List<MyItem> myList
{
    get
    {
         MyHost.GetItemFromID(_i1); //this may be a long operation
         MyHost.GetItemFromID(_i2);
         MyHost.GetItemFromID(_i3);
         MyHost.GetItemFromID(_i4);
         MyHost.GetItemFromID(_i5);
    }
}
```

This list needs sometimes to be retrieved as whole and other times only certain item has to be accessed: i.e. `myList[3]`. Is there a way of not building the entire list as I only need the fourth item?

Answer (score 5):

You could wrap the list with a class, say 'myListContainer' and overload its '[]' operator so that you could do something like this:

```
myListContainer[3]
```

which will invoke the call

```
 MyHost.GetItemFromID(_i3);
```

and return the desired list item.

I'll add a full example if needed

**EDIT**

```
 public class myListContainer
{

    public MyItem this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            return MyHost.GetItemFromID(i);
        }

    }
}
```

and add method to get the entire list.

Answer (score 3):

You could return `IEnumerable<MyItem>` and use [`yield return`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx):

```
public IEnumerable<MyItem> MyItems
{
    get
    {
        yield return MyHost.GetItemFromID(_i1); //this may be a long operation
        yield return MyHost.GetItemFromID(_i2);
        yield return MyHost.GetItemFromID(_i3);
        yield return MyHost.GetItemFromID(_i4);
        yield return MyHost.GetItemFromID(_i5);
    }
}
```

Then it is using deferred execution and you can write:

```
var fourItems = MyItems.Take(4).ToList();
```

Note that it might be a good idea to change the order of execution if the order doesn't matter and only the first call of `GetItemFromID` takes more time than the others:

```
yield return MyHost.GetItemFromID(_i2);
yield return MyHost.GetItemFromID(_i3);
yield return MyHost.GetItemFromID(_i4);
yield return MyHost.GetItemFromID(_i5);
yield return MyHost.GetItemFromID(_i1); //this may be a long operation
```

---

I think i have misuderstood the requirement. I've read *"sometimes I only need the fourth item"* as *"only need four items"*

So you could use my aproach but with `ElementAt`:

```
MyItem fourthItem = MyItems.ElementAt(3);
```

If you don't know if there's a fourth use `ElementAtOrdefault`.

Comment: This would still require unwanted ids to be loaded client is not interested in.

Comment: @nawfal: you're right, i've misunderstood _"sometimes I only need the fourth item"_. I've read it as _"only need four items"_

Comment: wouldn't ElementAt still go through all the items until the index? Your method, in other words, runs GetFromID calls of ids previous to the passed argument.

Comment: @Upvoters this is not what OP is after. Though code looks cool with LINQ ;)

Comment: @nawfal: true, it still needs to call all `GetItemFromID`. So personally i would prefer the `MyListContainer`-class apporach from barakcaf.

Answer (score 1):

## Note:

#### This assumes by '4th item' you mean an ordinal number, not the actual id itself.

---

Build a map in advance and return only items you wish to.

```
List<int> map = new List<int> 
{ 
    _i1,
    _i2, 
    _i3, 
    _i4, 
    _i5,     
};

public IEnumerable<MyItem> myList(params int[] indices)
{
    if (!indices.Any())
        return map.Select(MyHost.GetItemFromID);

    return indices.Select(i => MyHost.GetItemFromID(map[i]));
}

// so you call 
myList(); // for all items; decide on this API, may be separate to two methods?
myList(0); // or
myList(4); // or
myList(1, 3); // all loaded only on demand
```

Use a dictionary if you want more control over indexing. Ideally, for some reason this looks like you should be passing all IDs to DB in one go and SQL directly handle it, if that is the case.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what type your keys for `_i1` etc are, but let's assume they are ints. Then you could do this:

```
public IEnumerable<MyItem> GetItems(params int[] keys)
{
    return keys.Select(key => MyHost.GetItemFromID(key));
}
```

Which you could call like this:

```
var myItems = GetItems(_i2, _i3, _i5).ToList();
```

or

```
var myItems = GetItems(_i3).ToArray();
```

and so on.

Note: If you only ever want a list returned, you can do the conversion  inside `GetItems()` itself:

```
public List<MyItem> GetItems(params int[] keys)
{
    return keys.Select(key => MyHost.GetItemFromID(key)).ToList();
}
```

This approach requires a method rather than a property, though.

Comment: This is good. This assumes what is passed is the actual id that should go to `GetItemFromID` function. Not very obvious from OP.

Comment: @nawfal Agreed - could do with clarification from the OP.